# Sample instant app requires newer SDK

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm keep getting the error at the bottom of the question even though I followed official [emulator setup guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/setup.html#setup-emulator) and [sample project setup guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/first-instant-app.html) to the letter.

Using:
- Android Studio 3.0-Alpha7
- Pixel emulator with SDK 23

Provisioning succeeds and was able to enable instant apps in `Settings > Google > Instant Apps`

> Side loading instant app failed: Failure when trying to read bundle. Instant App com.instantappsample requires an SDK version which is newer than the one installed on device.  Please update the SDK on the device. 
>   Error while Uploading and registering Instant App

Comment: You say “Pixel emulator”, but the Emulator Setup Guide says, “Emulator: Nexus 5X image running Android 6.0 (API level 23), x86, with Google APIs.” clarify? (and Pixels don’t come with Marshmallow)

Comment: Documentation says that Pixel is among supported devices. Anyway, tested on Nexus 5X too. Same issue.

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948961/android-instant-apps-not-running-on-pixel or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908139/side-loading-instant-app-failed-reading-bundle-timed-out ?

Comment: They are unrelated.

Comment: Can you double check if your “Android 6.0 (API level 23), Google APIs x86” image is up-to-date in SDK manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an API 26 (aka O) emulator allowed me to successfully install the Instant App, while otherwise following the guide. Hat-tip to donly from [Github project android-instant-apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/issues/21) 
Workarounds I tried unsuccessfully first:

- Uninstalling "**Google Play Services for Instant Apps**" (from the other answer)
- Downgrading to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5
- Using a physical device that can run instant apps (Galaxy S6 SM-G920V, Android 7.0)

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue on our end. Thanks for reporting. Please try the following workaround:

- Settings -> Apps
- Find Google Play Services for Instant Apps.
- Uninstall this app.

You might get a notification when it's uninstalled, but please ignore it.

Now proceed to run your instant app again. This issue should go away.

Comment: That did not helped. After provisioning Google Play Services for Instant Apps version was 1.9-sdk-155682639

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 1):

It works for me to switch to API O X86 emulator.