# Unable to run android instant app in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

I have created an Instant app using Android Studio 3.0. When I try to run the instant app in the emulator I get the following error

[image]

I use the recommended **Nexus 5X image** running Android 6.0 (API level 23), x86, with Google APIs. I also have the Android Instant app SDK installed.

Following are my SDK versions,

- SDK Tools - 25.2.5
- SDK Platform tools - 26
- SDK Build tools - 26

And, this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myfirstinstantapp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

Comment: are you using emulator with Google APIs enabled? @ChandrasekarG

Comment: can you add build.gradle  here !! @ChandrasekarG

Comment: @ChiragTalsaniya Yes, I've used the emulator with Google APIs enabled. Have added the build.gradle in the question.

Comment: This is the gradle file of your installed app. The instant app gradle file will have `apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'`

Comment: Can you double check if your “Android 6.0 (API level 23), Google APIs x86” image is up-to-date in SDK manager?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Creating an API 26 (aka O) emulator allowed me to successfully install the Instant App, while otherwise following the guide. Hat-tip to donly from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/issues/21

---

This appears to be a Google bug; see [Sample instant app requires newer SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198979/sample-instant-app-requires-newer-sdk/45259218#45259218)

fwiw, these attempted workarounds failed:

- Uninstalling Google Play Services for Instant Apps, as suggested on that thread
- downgrading to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5
- using a real device (Galaxy S6/Android 7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Are not you using these settings?

```
Nexus 5X image running Android 6.0 (API level 23), x86_64, with Google APIs
```

There is a note in the documentation that says:

```
You cannot use x86_64 architectures of the operating system for testing instant apps on an emulator.
```

Check again if the settings were not used x86_64 instead of x86.